# Java Array: How do I make a lottery game?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I need to make a program that will make a lottery game.

My code supports 4 games, 6-42, MegaLotto(6-45), SuperLotto(6-49) and GrandLotto(6-55)
It would ask for which game to play, type 1 for 6-42 so on.

There are 10 players for the game each having non repeating random numbers in the lotto.
(ex. Player 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6 Player 2: 2,3,4,5,6,7 so on.)

There is the winning combination
(ex. Winning combination: 1,2,3,4,5,6)

How do I generate a new number in place of a repeated number?
(ex. 1,1,2,3,4,5 a repeated number will generate a new one thus, having 7,1,2,3,4,5)

My source code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

        int c1[]= new int[10];
        int a1[]= new int[6];
        int a2[]= new int[6];
        int a3[]= new int[6];
        int a4[]= new int[6];
        int a5[]= new int[6];
        int a6[]= new int[6];
        int a7[]= new int[6];
        int a8[]= new int[6];
        int a9[]= new int[6];
        int a10[]= new int[6];
        int aMaster[]= new int[6];

        int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
        int x,x1,x2,x3,x4;

        String help="";
        String holp="";
        char went='A';



        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        int numbers[]= new int[6];


    b= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Type [1] for 6-42\nType [2] for Mega\nType [3] for Super\nType [4] for Grand\nType [5] Go away and never come back!","Play!!!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE));

    while(b!=5)
    {
        switch(b)
            {

                case 1:

                    holp ="6-42 Lotto:\n";


                    for(x=0; x<a.length; x++)
                    {
                        a1[x]= AllGen(1,42);
                    }
                break;
            }
    }


}
```

AllGen is a number generator method say (1,42) will generate a random number between 1 and 42.

Comment: please give your question a suitable title, to improve the reach. The title you have described is very vast.

Comment: Set would typically be used to store unique numbers. If you have to use array, simply implement the set operations for your array ("contains?" and "add/insert") and loop getting new numbers until you have enough. Using array as set will guarantee all will be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [SET](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). This is a collection which doesn't allow repeated numbers. You can continue to add numbers until the list is the length you need. That way, every time a number is repeated, your loop will go one extra time. For instance, if you need 6 winning numbers that are between 0 - 50 you could use something like this:

```
Set winningNums = new TreeSet();
Random rand = new Random();

while (winningNums.size() < 6) {
    winningNums.add(rand.nextInt(51));
}

System.out.println(winningNums.toString());
```

You will need to integrate this into your program but this shows you how to generate a list of numbers with no repeats. I have used a `TreeSet` which orders the list, but if you don't need that there are others you can use.

Sample Outputs

```
[9, 10, 12, 24, 31, 37]
[1, 10, 11, 19, 43, 45]
[6, 20, 21, 33, 40, 48]
```

If 0 is not an allowed number you can just add 1 to the randomly generated int on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks csmckelvey!!! Very useful, but how do I make the same code without a set like if I use If and Else or switch?

Comment: You would need to first, generate your random number. Next, loop through your array and see _if_ that number is already contained there & if it is, generate a new random number and repeat, _else_ if it is not in the array, add it. If you need that fully done in code you might want to consider opening another question and specify exactly how you need it solved. And BTW, I wouldn't do this with if/else when a set can do this for you automatically.

Comment: I used the above code, but the compiler said omni5.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Probably because of the new code I inserted.

Comment: Well firstly, that is only a warning, not an error so it should still compile. Also, to tell you exactly what is causing this I would have to see the exact code you tried to compile because I compiled/ran this code without any warnings. If you just added my code to the code you posted above, it's probably from you parsing an int from an inputDialog with `JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE` option.

Comment: Okay, so I learned the hard way to answer this question,

My code:

    for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
    {
 if(x==0)
 {
           a1[x]= AllGen(1,6);
 }
      
 if(x>0)
 {
 a1[x]= AllGen(1,6);
 
          for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
   {
  if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
  x--;
   }
}

The code works like this:
First, it generates a number for an array named a1 onto the a1[0]
Next, if the loop x is greater than 1, it would check if it is the same as the previous numbers. Genious!!!